# Dovecot-imapd won't install properly after purging

Tags: debian, dovecot

I have been trying to get a dovecot/postfix server up an running to serve e-mail for my start up business, and I too have fallen victim to poorly written, outdated guides.

At first I installed Postfix and Dovecot, and selected an empty configuration thinking I'd configure it all myself. At a certain point I lost track of what I was actually doing and what I had configured, so I decided to `apt-purge` all the packages I had installed and start over.

After trying to install dovecot using `sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd`, I'm running into the following error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dovecot-imapd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/425 kB of archives.
After this operation, 565 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dovecot-imapd.
(Reading database ... 23009 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dovecot-imapd (from .../dovecot-imapd_1%3a2.1.7-7_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up dovecot-imapd (1:2.1.7-7) ...

Creating config file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf with new version
cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing dovecot-imapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-imapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I `dir` `/etc/`, I can't see a dovecot folder, and if I create it manually using `mkdir` and chmod it to 777, I still get the error that 20-imap.conf doesn't exist and that it cannot create a regular file.

I'm out of ideas here and would greatly appreciate any help you guys can give me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Purge `dovecot-common`, and try again?  Run `dpkg --get-selections | grep dovecot`, make sure every dovecot package is purged.  `dpkg -P packagename`, if you have already removed it, but not purged the files.

Once you are sure all the dovecot packages are gone, make sure you delete the `/etc/dovecot` directory that you tried to manually create.

The `/etc/dovecot`, and `/etc/dovecot/conf.d` belong to the `dovecot-common` package.  Deleting only the dovecot-imapd package would not have deleted those directories.  I am guessing you manually removed them, or something else weird happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I ensure I have purged and removed all the dovecot related packages? when I run `dpkg --get-selections | grep dovecot` I get a list of packages that don't include common and imapd - are those installed on my system too or are those the available packages?

Comment: The `dpkg --get-selections` shows you what is installed, or in a removed state.  If you have other dovecot packages, you probably need to remove those as well.

Comment: After having played with this until deep in the night I finally managed to get it working thanks to your answer. Marking your answer as accepted, thanks for the help!

Comment: I had to remove dovecot-core too (thanks to `dpkg --get-selections | grep dovecot`)

Answer (score -2):

```
    apt-get purge....

    based on dpkg --get-selections | grep dovecot (which was a life saver) the output should be:
    dovecot-core     install(those 2 remain no matter what one is using aptitude or apt)
    then run:
    type dovecot
    dovecot is /usr/sbin/dovecot
    rm /usr/sbin/dovecot
    rm -r /etc/dovecot
    dpkg -P 'dovecot-core'(ignore warnings)and dont forget the ''.

    After this do a clean install.
```